# woocommerce checkout update shipping value more than once

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce allows the use of the code below to update the shipping cost.

```
$('body').trigger('update_checkout', { update_shipping_method: true });
```

Am using a custom shipping plugin and am able to update the cost through ajax and eventually update my total.
The problem is, the update_checkout can only work when the billing_address_1, billing_city, shipping_city and a few other fields have been changed. So I have to do something like below:

```
$("#billing_address_1").trigger("keypress").val(function(i,val){return val + ' -';});
$('body').trigger('update_checkout', { update_shipping_method: true });
```

Is there a better way to achieve this, other than make the form dirty for woocommerce to update the shipping cost?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This by design of woocommerce. This scripts assumes that update is needed when changing address or country.

```
  jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');

  /* what this does is update the order review table but what it doesn't do is update shipping costs;
     the calculate_shipping function of your shipping class will not be called again;
     so if you were like me and you made a shipping method plugin and you had to change costs based on payment method then
     this is the only way to ensure it does just that
  */
```

If you want to make things work add this (to plugin file or functions.php):

```
function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review($array, $int)
{
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
    return;
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 10, 2);
```

Quotation from: https://gist.github.com/neamtua/bfdc4521f5a1582f5ad169646f42fcdf

For reson why, read this ticet:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12349

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I also have figured out that, jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout'); works always But does not update on the client side. I used ajax to fetch the Shipping cost and I got the figure as updated but on the checkout page it could not update, and on submitting the order, the value on the client checkout page is used and not the one on WC session. I was using WC session variable to update the shipping cost rate array.

Comment: I have plain wordpress install with storefront and triggering dom event, reloads shipping costs. Often in wordpress other plugins break some behaviors. Are you sure all fields are populated correctly? Can you give me a link to site with this issue?

Comment: cant expose the url now: My shipping plugin uses google map to display route and one has to click services options like "same day delivery", " 1 week delivery" e.t.c, which returns the new shipping value. This shipping value is submitted by ajax to WC->session variable then checkout_update is triggered WC does the rest. I can email u link..

Comment: Sure, if you still have  an issue email me daniel[at]pikselownia.com