# WooCommerce Shipping Plugin - Checkout Shipping Cost Not Updating(AJAX)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I've searched to find any solution but nothing worked.

#### Here what I want to do:

1. Add new field in checkout page called **Shipping** show as selectbox filled with `Preorder` and `Non-preorder`
2. If `preorder` then would show **Location** field show as selectbox
3. If `non-preorder` then would show **Location** field same as step 2 but different list option.
4. When **Shipping** and **Location** filled correctly, shipping cost would show with correct shipping cost.

---

#### Problem

When I filled all required field and **Shipping**, **Location** shipping cost wound calculate again. It do AJAX request, but shipping cost keep the same.

But, when I change **Name** or **Street Address** shipping cost updated correctly, which is bad behavior. When user click **Place Order** immediately  would POST wrong shipping cost.

Here my [Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/8vBecfuDFyk) to make clear what I ask for help.

---

#### What I did to create my own plugin:

1. Create custom field using hook something like this

```
    public function woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields )
    {
        // var_dump(have_rows('location', 'option'));
        // die('test');

        $options = [];

        $options[''] = 'Select Shipping';
        $options['pre-order'] = 'Pre Order';
        if (!$this->hasPreorderItem()) {
            $options['non-pre-order'] = 'Non Pre Order';
        }

        // Add custom billing shipping
        $fields['billing']['billing_shipping'] = array (
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => 'Shipping',
            'placeholder' => 'Select shipping',
            'class' => array ('address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
            'required' => true,
            'options' => $options
            // 'options' => $this->getLocations()
        );

        $fields['billing']['billing_location_pre_order'] = array (
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => 'Location(Pre Order)',
            'placeholder' => 'Select Preorder Location',
            'class' => array ('address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
            'required' => false,
            'options' => $this->preorderLocations->getLocations()
            // 'options' => $this->getLocations()
        );

        // Add custom billing location
        $fields['billing']['billing_location'] = array (
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => 'Location',
            'placeholder' => 'Select location',
            'class' => array ('address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
            'required' => false,
            'options' => $this->locations->getLocations()
            // 'options' => $this->getLocations()
        );

        return $fields;
    }
```

2. Create class to help calculate cost based on **Shipping** and **Location**.

---

#### What I have tried

1. Using this answer but no luck. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129882/woocommerce-checkout-update-shipping-value-more-than-once) for the question.
2. Tried to make field to required, as I saw someone said it only update when all required fields filled.
3. Tried to disable cache in `wp-config.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution from [this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/310886/calling-calculate-shipping-with-ajax-in-woocommerce)

I might help someone that has similar problem. You just need to **clear the session**. So, WooCommerce would re-calculate and recall your `calculate_shipping()` function.

To do that add `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review` hook. It would look something like this

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 10, 1);
function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review( $posted_data )
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $packages = $woocommerce->cart->get_shipping_packages();
    foreach( $packages as $package_key => $package ) {
        $session_key  = 'shipping_for_package_'.$package_key;
        $stored_rates = WC()->session->__unset( $session_key );
    }
}
```